# Having trouble formatting code to solve for Standard Deviation of a 2D array

Tags: c++, arrays

Most of my code for the program is completed. I need help with the standard deviation. When I run the program, it compiles and gives me values, but I think the std value is not correct. I don't think using `arr[ROWS][COLS]` is the best way to go about it, but I used it anyway to show all of the values in the array. I think that is what is giving me the incorrect output. How do I fix it? Use a different way to show each value, but how? The loop should run 24 times. Each time it will use like say `number[0]` - average and then keep it and then add it to say `number[1]` - average all the way till it hits the max amount of numbers in the array.

---

Here is a formula for standard deviation.

- s is the standard deviation.
- M is the mean or average. -----> I already have double average as M
- n is the number of values in the array. -------> I have MAX_VALUES equal to n.

  ### * X is for each value in the array.

  ```
  89 93 23 89 78 99
  95 21 87 92 90 89
  94 88 65 44 89 91
  77 92 97 68 74 82
  ```

---

```
//To calculate standard deviation of 2-D array
double getStandardDeviation(int arr[ROWS][COLS], double &std, double average, int num, const int MAX_VALUES)
{
    double devSum = 0; //sum of every value in array minus the average that is then squared 
    for (int x = 0; x < MAX_VALUES; x++)
    {
        devSum += pow((arr[ROWS][COLS] - average), 2); 
    }
    std = sqrt(devSum / (MAX_VALUES - 1)); 

    return std; 
}
//end of getStandardDeviation method
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error in `getStandardDeviation` is that you are using the wrong indices, `ROW` and `COL`, for every value of `x`.

Instead of

```
for (int x = 0; x < MAX_VALUES; x++)
{
   devSum += pow((arr[ROWS][COLS] - average), 2);
                   // ^^^^^^^^^^^ Wrong indices 
}
```

use

```
double square(double x)
{
   return x*x;
}

for ( int r = 0; r < ROWS; ++r )
{
   for ( int c = 0; c < COLS; ++c )
   {
      // Use of pow(..., 2) is not necessary.
      // devSum += pow((arr[r][c] - average), 2); 

      // Use a more efficient method.
      devSum += square(arr[r][c] - average);
   }
}
```

Comment: But don't use `pow(t, 2)`, instead use `t * t`.  It's much much faster.

Comment: I don't understand why the double square(double x) should be included. I understand the two for loops. I tried to do that earlier but used i and j instead of r and c. The devSum is the sum of each value minus average and then squared. The devSum is divided by total number of values - 1. Then it is squared. Never mind. I have figured out how to solve for it.